# how router works in ROR 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

HI i am new to rails i started working on one existing project. i want to integrate new page to website. I created new page under folder Sites(page name xxxx.html.erb) which have controller named sites.and created method within controller

```
def xxxx

end
```

when i tried access that page following error is showing

The action 'show' could not be found for SitesController

i think it is problem with routes.rb file please help me 
i tried to add this
match "xxxx" => "Sites#xxxx" but not working .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all i got answer problem with i used capital "**S**" in Sites routes file and used capital "**s**" in link also `<%= link_to "Profile", :controller => "**Sites**", :action => "xxxxx"%>`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a controller named it as SitesController, in this controller you can add the xxxx action.

2 . Then you need add routes in config/routes.rb file. For your reference http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html